# Motion Event Capturing in android

Tags: android

i have written code for an application.

The application layout is like this.

0 1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8 9

now when the user touches one key(The user hold his finger on a button say 5),that its text  should be entered in text box as "5 down". But when the user releases the key then the text should be  set to "5 up". but before the key release done, if the user slides on the layout with his finger to 6 , then it should be detected and the text should be set to "down 6". it should proceed like that ,but when the user releases the key then the text should be set to  "up **the key currently touched**". i have used the MOTION_UP,MOTION_DOWN , MOTION_MOVE things but i am not getting how to accomplish it exactly. please throw some light for me on this issue. what is happening is when i slide from 5 to 6, the event is still in "down 5" but when i take off my finger then it is setting to "up 5". but i want the sliding approach to be done. so please give me some idea of how to do this.

here is my code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // select_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    // home_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);
    et.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    b = new Bundle();


    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mybtn.length; i++) {
        String btnid = "btn" + i;
        int resid = getResources().getIdentifier(btnid, "id",
                getPackageName());
        mybtn[i] = (Button) findViewById(resid);
        mybtn[i].setOnTouchListener(this);

    }



}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s = null;
    s = ((Button) v).getText().toString().trim();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    // case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    // Do some stuff
    // et.setText("move android"+s, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE );
    // break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        et.setText("down android" + s, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        // Do some stuff
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        et.setText("up android" + s, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: post some code/xml of what you did

Comment: i have tried MOTION_UP,MOTION_DOWN , MOTION_MOVE and some other values, but i am not getting how to get it. please help me

Comment: i think it need to be handled with onInterceptTouchEvent .i am not understanding it.please suggest ur views

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but i guess it should work:

```
private int currentSelected = 0;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    String s = null;

    s = ((Button) v).getText().toString().trim();

    switch (event.getAction())
    {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            currentSelected = Integer.valueOf(s);
            et.setText("down android" + s, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            et.setText("up android" + currentSelected, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (Integer.valueOf(s) != currentSelected)
            {
              et.setText("down android" + s, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
              currentSelected = Integer.valueOf(s);
            }
            break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It is not working,the application is opening and working in the old way, after some time  getting closed forcibly by throwing some runtime exception