# onInterceptTouchEvent to disable ACTION_DOWN/ MOVE/UP

Tags: android, touch-event

i have coded a program which which does a task like this

0 1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8 9

suppose these are the views in my layout. Now suppose user has touched (down event) on 1,some string is set to "1 down". but when the user slides to 2 without releasing his finger on key 1 , then it should set the string to "2 down", but the string is still "1 down".. i am not getting how to make this possible .it may have to be done on ACTION_MOVE  event of 1 . but i am not getting what to do ,to disable its further events (Up event). after the entire sliding  when i release the key the string is set to "1 up". so it is not recognizing the motion down events of 2 3 4 etc. it is staying in down mode. i think it could be done with
onInterceptTouchEvent, but i did not get it correctly .below is my source code. share ur views on it.if possible give me some sample code on how to incorporate it into my code

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);


// select_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
// home_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);
et.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
b = new Bundle();


try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for (int i = 0; i < mybtn.length; i++) {
    String btnid = "btn" + i;
    int resid = getResources().getIdentifier(btnid, "id",
            getPackageName());
    mybtn[i] = (Button) findViewById(resid);
    mybtn[i].setOnTouchListener(this);

}
```

}
.

Answer (score 0):

Move "int current = 0;" out of onTouch method.
It is being called any time there's a movement on the screen and put 0 in current.

by the way, I see you used my code (part of it):
[Motion Event Capturing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329595/motion-event-capturing-in-android#comment11777807_9329595)

the least you can do is to accept the answer or mark it as useful

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion,but it is of no use. The application is not working. and for this to work i assume onInterceptTouchEvent need to be used, but i am understanding that method at all. if u know about it please help me,how to use it in my code.